# Java: Finding object reference while inside method

Tags: java, oop, object, methods

I am currently trying to set up a Tic Tac Toe GUI grid with 3x3 buttons, which change the button icon to a nought or cross whenever pressed.

I have set up an array of JButtons and have added a listener to check whenever the button is pressed.

My problem is getting access to the Button object inside the array, I have had to add a parameter to my custom listener constructor to save the button object reference for when I want to change it. It works as is, but doesn't feel very elegant. Is there a way to find the correct JButton object in buttons while inside actionPerformed, or is there a better way to do this altogether?

Thanks in advance

```
class BigPanel
{
    public JPanel bigPanel= new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,3));
    public JButton[][] buttons = new JButton[3][3];

    public BigPanel()
    {
        for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<3; j++)
            {
                buttons[i][j] = new JButton();
                buttons[i][j].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(75,75));

                // Line of interest, adding the listener
                buttons[i][j].addActionListener(new CustomActionListener(buttons[i][j]));

                bigPanel.add(buttons[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }   
}

class CustomActionListener implements ActionListener
{
    public int a;
    public int b;
    public JButton button;

    CustomActionListener(JButton a)
    {
        button = a;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        changeButton(a, b, CurrPlayer.CROSSES);
    }

    public void changeButton(int a, int b, CurrPlayer player)
    {
        if (player == CurrPlayer.NOUGHTS)
        {
            Icon icon = new ImageIcon("Nought.jpg");
            button.setIcon(icon);
        }
        else
        {
            Icon icon = new ImageIcon("Cross.jpg");
            button.setIcon(icon);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see how your listener is going to work at all.  The x and y coordinates of the button never gets set.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean, could you explain? I've managed to get the listener to change the button image whenever it is pushed so far.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `CustomActionListener` to following will solve this problem

```
class CustomActionListener implements ActionListener {
    public int a;
    public int b;

    CustomActionListener()
    {
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        JButton button = (JButton) e.getSource();
        changeButton(a, b, CurrPlayer.CROSSES, button);
    }

    public void changeButton(int a, int b, CurrPlayer player, JButton button)
    {
        if (player == CurrPlayer.NOUGHTS)
        {
            Icon icon = new ImageIcon("Nought.jpg");
            button.setIcon(icon);
        }
        else
        {
            Icon icon = new ImageIcon("Cross.jpg");
            button.setIcon(icon);
        }
    }
}
```

You can get `JButton` reference using `actionEvent.getSource()` method.

And add action listener to buttons as below

```
buttons[i][j].addActionListener(new CustomActionListener());
```

Hope this'll help you.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Yeah, it worked perfectly, but now I need to figure out a way to access the bigPanel from the action be able to change the image once the cell has been won.

Comment: In that case, you need reference of `bigPanel` in `CustomActionListener` class